# How to record Selenium Script for Popups?

Tags: java, selenium, popup

I want to record selenium script for Popup coming in the middle of website. I recorded the selenium script for the site, and when I ran it then in the middle of the processing I got advertisement popup, it is stopping my script execution.

How can I remove those popup or handle it using selenium?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If its an advertisement then I think it would be a new window, you can use getallwindowtitles, then loop thru the result to get to the adv window, use selectwindow and then close the window using close.  Return back using selectwindow(0)

Answer (score 0):

You can download and use Auto it. Following is the sample of the script that waits for a pop up title and then close it when appears.

```
While 1
    $activeWindowTitle = WinGetTitle(WinActive(""));            
    If ($activeWindowTitle == "popuptitle") Then
       WinClose("popuptitle");
    EndIf           
    sleep(500)
WEnd
```